# Bintray new version is not synced to JCenter eventhough my package is accepted in JCenter

Tags: maven, bintray, jcenter

My Bintray package is **already accepted in JCenter**. When it got accepted Version 1 automatically got added to JCenter. After few hours I Uploaded Version 2 to Bintray. It has been more than 2 days now, My Version 2 is not synced with JCenter.
I have a Pro account.
Anybody know how long it takes to sync new version to JCenter from Bintray?

The new version is shown in following URL

```
https://<organization>.bintray.com/<repository>/<group-id>/<artifcat-id>/
```

But not in following URL

```
http://jcenter.bintray.com/<group-id>/<artifcat-id>/
```

Both versions have the same group-id and artifact-id, which i mean to say is structure wise both looks the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with JFrog Support.

Thank you for letting us know.

Please reach out to us using the 'Feedback' widget on the right side of your Bintray profile page. It would be great to have the entire details about the sync problem you mentioned. We will further investigate and keep you updated accordingly.

Cheers, Guy.